# Android WebViewClient Differentiate between clicks and redirects

Tags: android, webview, webviewclient

I've overridden the "WebViewClient" object, and I'm looking to differentiate when the user CLICKS on a link - and therefore they've actually requested it, and when an intermediate server redirects the request.

For example - Wifi's that require a logon will re-direct to their login page when a browser is launched. This will attempt to load this page in a webview too.

When a user clicks on a html link - (assuming it's not redirected) this will be a true request.

Is there anything with webviewclient that I can override/ intercept/call to make this distinction?

Comment: Sorry I understand it has been a while... Just curious did you find a solution?